# How can I set an attribute based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to do something like this:

```
var Layers = {
            TL: null,
            TM: null,
            TT: null,
            MF: null,
            BT: null,
            BM: null,
            BL: null};

Layers.(file.layer) = file.id;
```

Where file.layer, is actually the 'key' to set file.id, inside Layers...
So, is there a way, or it can only be done using arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Layers[file.layer] = file.id;
```

...

Comment: Does it work with object, and not arrays also? Oh, i tested it. Works also! Thanks

Comment: and how do i iterate the object, getting the key, and the value?

Comment: @Ivan Seidel: `for (var i in obj) { ... }` --- `i` - key, `obj[i]` - value

Comment: Very nice! Objects and Arrays are almost the same then... lol

Comment: @Ivan Seidel—javascript Arrays **are** Objects, they just have a special length property and handy inherited methods that can mostly be applied to any suitable object. Array property names are strings (even the numeric ones).